# Instead of finding elements from selectors in jquery can I do the other way around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Usually we search elements by selectors in libraries like jquery but what happens if we want to make the other way around: given an element we want to find all rules applied to it like firebug does it!

This kind of job is necessary if we want to bring a css file and update it so we can see live results in our webpage.
In firebug by selecting an element we can see in reverse order all the rules that were applied to it.

First, we have to find the document's style rules and retrieve their contents as a text so user can update them but the real problem is to find the relation between an element and all the rules....

Is this possible even with the help of a library like jquery?

Comment: Anything is possible, but could you explain why you need this a little better, as updating the page with "live results" doesn't really sound like something where you would need to know all the styles and properties of an element ?

Comment: The number of possible selectors for every element on a page would be enormous, e.g. a single element might be selectable by ID, any number of classes and index, parent/child relationships with index, attribute values, property values and pesudo–classes, just to name a few. How would you determine which selector to use?

Comment: Go get the firefox source code and locate the function [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) and see how it works

Comment: Firebug can tap into browser rendering engine...don't have same access using script from inside the window. Would do a lot better explaining your objectives in more detail

Comment: I understand one couldn't possible imagine what I have in my head; to give an explanation: say a page is composed (with my php lib) by one menu, one slider and one context. Suppose I call them modules,everyone comes from distict files of type: *.css, *.js, *.html snippets (document fragments) included at the head/bottom one-by-one (to easy things). Now, at the client browser all we have to do is build a node tree and start findind/changing selectors and rules in order to save them back at the server. That's the whole idea!

Comment: @gwillie I've worked with getComputedStyle at the past and that can't help in this problem: it estimates the end result, we need the beginning of this i.e. the actual applied rules!

Comment: @charlietfl I dissagree, we do have enormous powers from a simple window otherwise javascript wouldn't even existed!

Comment: @centurian for someone who seems to have all the answers....why haven't you provided an attempt in code

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for opinions about what tools can one use to tackle such a problem in the restrictions applied by a browser environment...

My opinion is that we have to make a brute search attack at the css files/selectors and construct the dependencies: suppose we have 100 rules for a page with 100 elements the possible combinations are 10^4 as the relations are many-to-many.

Then, we can build 'tables' in memory (hash arrays) that might excced 10^4 records if we want to keep the cascading order of rules for an element.

Anyway, my point is that I wouldn't dare to put jquery in such a pain! If we can 'transplant' the heart of jquery, it's search engine I mean.

It seems that it's heart listens to the name of 'sizzle' but it's a waste of time here (regular expressions? no thanks). I think the real 'heart' is a simple word: '`querySelectorAll`' and now we are running with native speeds here...

just an opinion since I don't care about wide/old browser support.